# Installing 3rd party JARs to Jenkins .m2 repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar

I am Trying to add a third party jar to jenkis .m2 repository

This is the command i found to add it to the repository from command line

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

i have a linux machine where jenkins run by its own user. it has a .m2 repository in the home directory. when i tried the above command it gives error saying that, The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:* maven * maven2 . so jenkins can build with out a maven installed?, if so how it is done?. how can i add the jar to .m2 repository without installing maven ?

i read that maven need a setting.xml file in its .m2 folder, but i cant find any for jenkins.

Comment: which environment are you on? You probably need to install maven (`apt-get install maven` or `yum install maven`) or set the PATH variable to point to the bin/-dir of your manual maven installation. BTW, you do not need to install a third-party jar if it is available in a public repo - in this case, just run `mvn install` and the jar will be downloaded by maven

Comment: is there any other way with out installing the maven?. since i already have a .m2 repository and jenkins is picking from that

Comment: `so jenkins can build with out maven installed` it use maven plugin. can you please put some light on this

Comment: @Alexander, thats is a possible way to install maven manually . but can i use the maven plugin used by jenkins to do that?

Comment: I'm not using jenkins, but does the the maven plugin provide a `mvn` binary? try `find / -type f -name mvn` - it should show you the mvn binary. You can then change `mvn install:install-file ...` to `<pathFromFind>/mvn install:install-file ...` or add this path to your PATH variable.

Comment: @Alexander add your comment as answer it worked for me. there is a bin folder in jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the maven binary from the jenkin's `maven-plugin`. Use `find / -type f -name mvn` to find out, where the **jenkins maven plugin** is installed to and call `mvn` from there.

You can then change `mvn install:install-file ...` to `<pathFromFind>/mvn install:install-file ...` or add this path to your PATH variable.